# Is there any api for Microsoft Graph to update project name a user is assigned to?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

There is a user x he is assigned to project y now if I want to update his project from y to z is there any api to do that in microsoft graph? Do I need to create a new project in using graph api how I can do that?

Comment: Please let us know do you want to update the application display name or  let us know the property details which you looking for updation

Comment: Are you still looking any help on this question